# "Not implemented" when calling showComposeNewEmailAsync

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8.1

On a Windows 8.1 Phone device a Cordova app plugin is accessing showComposeNewEmailAsync here is the code;

```
exports.open = function (success, error, args) {
var props = args[0],
    email = exports.getDraftWithProperties(props);

Windows.ApplicationModel.Email.EmailManager
    .showComposeNewEmailAsync(email)
    .then(function () {
        success();
    },
    function (err) {
        error(err);
    })
    .done(success, 
    function (err) {
        error(err);
    });
};
```

I get an error of "Not Implemented", it would seem from other posts that this method is available on this platform. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

It seems EmailManager.ShowComposeNewEmailAsync throws an exception when called from a background (non-UI) thread.

Use something like the below to invoke the code in the UI/main thread:

```
Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(async () =>
{             
 await EmailManager.ShowComposeNewEmailAsync(msg);
});
```

Comment: "On a Windows 8.1 Phone device a Cordova app plugin..." will your code work in that environment?

Comment: I reproduced the exception and tested the fix in a Cordova App in WP 8.1 Emulator